# Measuring correlation at national level from state level data?

Tags: python, pearson-r

I have a dataset with 96 records in the following format:

```
State           Period      WHC     WVC
Aguascalientes  2010-2011   79,333  118,192
Aguascalientes  2015-2016   79,802  60,427
Aguascalientes  2020-2021   89,301  73,652
Baja California 2010-2011   178,822 247,565
Baja California 2015-2016   169,765 101,350
Baja California 2020-2021   174,783 124,263
```

'State' is one of the 32 Mexican states; 'Period' is one of three sample periods; 'WHC' is a count of women with moderate-severe food insecurity; and 'WVC' is a count of women experiencing violence.

Pearson regression run in Python against all 96 records for WCH and WVC yields the following:

```
PearsonRResult(statistic=0.8286902722280343, pvalue=2.0050767218356561e-25)
```

With this information, I believe I am correct in asserting:

1. There is a strong (0.83) linear relationship between hunger and violence nationally.
2. It is extremely unlikely the relationship occurred by chance (null hypothesis rejected).

When I run regression on the data at a state level (three samples each) I see as expected a wide range of r-values, and only three of the state samples have a p-value < .05.

Couple of questions:

- With more data collected (i.e. filling in the gaps in years), we would expect to see more significant correlations at a state level?
- Would we expect with 95% confidence the strength of those
  relationships (slope of blue line) to fall within the shaded interval below (default value regplot)?
- Do I need to think about this differently since the samples were taken at different times?

[image]

Of course I'm ignoring confounding variables here (like poverty) that will be part of the discussion.

Edit: responding to @ute comments below

Thanks for the good questions - they made me think more about this and do some digging. The states are very different in size of course, with the largest being 14% of the total population (across all three time periods) and the smallest being 0.6%. I have rates available, however if I use those then I would be treating all the sample sizes as equal. Running Pearson on the rates I get a very weak correlation (r=1.6, p=.11), but that would shift the focus to analyzing rate differences by state which is not my research question.

As you suggested, there is indeed an interesting variance in the data by time, with total violence reports in 2010 more than 2x of those in 2015 (hunger does not follow this pattern):

[image]

I checked to see if this was an outlier in the data, but the effect is seen across all the states, leading me to think it is either a measurement change or some other less likely phenomenon:

[image]

Finally I reran Pearson against all three time periods (on total counts) to see what I could learn, and all three produced strong, significant correlations:

```
        
Period       r-value   p-value                             
2010-2011    0.957437  9.733679e-18
2015-2016    0.871691  8.366862e-11
2020-2021    0.901341  1.994013e-12
```

Am I on the right track with my method and findings?

Edit: Responding to second round of comments. I can see that the larger states impact the Pearson results (did it by hand to see), but conversely considering just the rates seems equally problematic and vulnerable to small sample variance. I tried two approaches:

1. Run Spearman instead of Pearson by period to reduce the impact of outliers; this produces slightly weaker but still strong, significant correlations.
2. Add weights by multiplying rate x count, then running Pearson and Spearman by period. Now results are further weakened.

Here are the results:

```
Pearson by Period - Counts
            r-value       p-value
Period                           
2010-2011  0.957437  9.733679e-18
2015-2016  0.871691  8.366862e-11
2020-2021  0.901341  1.994013e-12

Spearman by Period - Counts
            r-value       p-value
Period                           
2010-2011  0.920088  9.605107e-14
2015-2016  0.874633  6.030124e-11
2020-2021  0.874267  6.284060e-11

Pearson by Period - Counts x Rates
            r-value       p-value
Period                           
2010-2011  0.900054  2.400698e-12
2015-2016  0.616009  1.744375e-04
2020-2021  0.686044  1.463182e-05

Spearman by Period - Counts x Rates
            r-value       p-value
Period                           
2010-2011  0.766862  3.077595e-07
2015-2016  0.707845  5.862840e-06
2020-2021  0.755499  5.781732e-07
```

Are either of these reasonable approaches?

Comment: Is it correct that the results are based on raw counts from states with quite different population size? Then the strong and very significant correlation could be due to correlation of case counts with total population in the states (confounder) Have you also tried to divide whc and wvc by population size and analyze the resulting rates (cases per inhabitant) in the same way?

Comment: From looking at the figures from two states you gave, it seems that in 2010 more violence cases than hunger cases were reported, while it was the opposite in 2015 and 2020. You could calculate the ratio whc/wvc for all states and years to see if year does matter

Comment: Responded to @Ute above.

Comment: Almost *any* state-based counts will be strongly correlated solely because of the variation in state populations.  You need to be analyzing *proportions*.

Comment: Nive informative plots, and interesting phenomenon with the wvc drop - there might indeed be administrative changes behind. I would say, you are on the right track concerning treating years separately. The strong correlation is however due to using absolute counts with such big differences in population size. So the conclusion from these would be doubtful.

Comment: You are right in that it would be appropriate to take population size into account. This can be done by weighting the rates data. But quite likely, you will still not get high correlation between whr and wvr (r for rate instead of c for count)

Comment: If you are concerned about the effect of treating sample sizes as equal, you could make a small simulation experiment for yourself: take the rates and generate artificial counts from states of size 100000, say, by simulating from a binomial distribution. Compare your analysis results to what you get if you do the same simulation, but with true population sizes

Comment: +1 to @whuber s comment. This is only irrelevant if all states have the same population, or if the things you count have nothing to do with population size. To get a feeling, you can try out the effects by simulation as I just suggested.

Comment: See comments above.

Comment: Would using Spearman and/or adding weights be a reasonable approach? See notes above.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I consulted with a statistician who was finally able to break through my mental block: the reason for the high correlation in counts between violence and hunger is because both are highly correlated with population size (like saying that the number of left handed people and doctors have a strong relationship). So we have shifted the approach to analyze the relationship in rates, using weights for population size. He believes this will show a modest positive correlation.